# java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to read data from my underlying mysql database using hadoop map reduce but am getting this exception even after adding mysql jar file to hadoop/lib folder.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeNewSplits(JobSubmitter.java:470)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.writeSplits(JobSubmitter.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:387)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1218)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$11.run(Job.java:1215)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1236)
    at DBCountPageView.run(DBCountPageView.java:227)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at DBCountPageView.main(DBCountPageView.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:163)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:148)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:189)
    ... 22 more
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you using maven add dependency for jdbc.driver othervise download jar file with it and add it to your classpath

Answer (score 1):

Youu have to download `mysql-connector-java-version-bin.jar` and add it ro your classpath. See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-binary-installation.html) for more details.

Comment: I added jar to my classpath

Comment: Where you have added it and how do your run your application?

Comment: i have added jar file in hadoop/lib folder and am running my application hadoop jar myapp.jar MainClass -libjars

Comment: Use `hadoop classpath` to find out if your jar is in classpath.

Comment: ya my jar is in hadoop classpath